# HTML MySQL encoding character and simplepie

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, simplepie

I have the following issue with character encoding witch I don't know how to solve it. I'm building a website where it is necessary to grab feeds from custom news sites and store it in my own database.

The thing is that for some feeds are stored fine with the german umlauts as they are (ä,ü,ß). But for other feeds the german umlauts are converted to "Java fÃ¼r Mac" or "Fehler in CoreText lÃ¤sst OS-X- und iOS-Apps abstÃ¼rzen".

The database setting is utf8_general_ci, also when i save some field directly in the database the german umlauts are saved ok.

For loading the feeds i use the simplepie 1.3 library and have set also the input-output character encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) - If the data is coming from different sources, apparently in different encodings, you need to parse their meta data (HTTP headers perhaps) and convert them accordingly.

Comment: Apart from what @deceze commented (which is a good read btw.), there can be also an additional issue: As encoding is hard to understand for many programmers and webauthors, who says that it's not the feed itself which contains the wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably no charset selected in your html document.

Comment: I've set header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); right in the beginning of the document, still not working

Comment: The html code itself needs a [charset option](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp):

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

or for HTML5

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: @tea It's a good idea to include an HTML charset meta tag, but it's *not needed*. The HTTP header always takes precedence and should always be set. Further the OP says that it does work for some sources and not for others.

Comment: Everyday something new to learn. Thx deceze. Another problem could be a messed up template with wrong encoding. Seems like the BOM can take precedence over the header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102925/prefer-charset-declaration-in-html-meta-tag-or-http-header